# npm error in vscode that seems to stem from running on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra

I was loaned an iMac from 2011 to replace my PC when it abruptly went on strike on me. I am not very familiar with macOS.

I am trying to use the terminal in VSCode to work and the command `npm start` yields this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Here's what I gathered from my googling and contacting Apple:

- It seems this would be solved by a more current version of the OS but this device cannot handle anything past HighSierra.
- There should be other workarounds.
- I found the Apple Discussion "[SSH BROKE dyld: lazy symbol binding failed](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251638718)" which says

  > This is a PATH issue.
  > PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Only I don't really understand what to do with that or whether that even applies to my issue.

I hope someone here can help.

Answer (score 1):

For old versions of OSX/macos to get open source software  which includes node you could install [Macports](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html) - this provides many ports of more modern software (usually already built) on all versions of OSX since Snow Leopard and  a lesser amount back to Tiger.

This includes several versions of  node and probably supports a version newer than nodejs.org has compiled for High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a `node` version which was compiled for macOS 10.15 (High Sierra is 10.13). You could try one of the older node versions on https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/, e.g. https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.10.0/